# Proof of a limit with factorial

Tags: limits

The limit of $\frac{x!}{x^x}$ is proven by the sandwich theorem according to the following logic.

Factorials of negative numbers don't exist, so $\frac{x!}{x^x}=\frac{x}{x}\frac{x-1}{x}\cdots\frac{1}{x} \ge 0$.
Again looking at the expansion we see that $\frac{x}{x}=1$ and all other terms $\frac{x-k}{x} \le 1$ and what remains is $\frac{1}{x}$. So $\frac{x!}{x^x} \le 1\times\frac{1}{x}$. Now by sandwich theorem both $0$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ go to $0$ as $x$ approaches infinity. And hence our desired limit is $0$.

But here are a couple of things I don't understand. First one is the $\ge 0$ part. How can equality occur here? If it were to be $0$ then $x$ had to be $0$. But then $\frac{0!}{0^0}=\frac{1}{0^0}$ wouldn't make any sense. Secondly how can the equality case in $\le 1$ take place? $\frac{x-k}{x}$ is strictly less than $1$ for all $k$ ranging from $1$ to $x-1$. So I don't understand how there can be an equality again. And the most important doubt is that why did we leave the term $\frac{1}{x}$ at the end? Why didn't we treat it like the rest of the terms like $\frac{2}{x},\frac{3}{x},\cdots,\frac{x-1}{x}$ and say that $\frac{1}{x} <1$. I don't understand the logic behind keeping only the $\frac{1}{x}$ term at the end but say that $\frac{2}{x}<1$ whereas both don't make much difference, i.e., both approach to $0$ when $x$ goes to infinity. So if we took $\frac{1}{x}<1$,then we would have got $0<\frac{x!}{x^x}<1$ and we can no longer use sandwich theorem now.

Please point out the mistakes I am making and enlighten me by providing the correct concept.

Comment: $a \ge 0$ does not imply that $a=0$ must happen. Likewise, $b \le 1$ does not imply that $b=1$ must occur. Keeping only $1/x$ is enough because it is sufficient to conclude and it makes the argument simple.

Comment: If $a=0$ can't happen,why is it necessary to write $a \ge 0$. Wouldn't it be appropriate to write $a>0$ instead? Also could you please elaborate? I am finding it difficult to follow you,maybe because i am dumb.

Comment: it is not necessary to write $a\ge0$, but why would you write something stronger such as $a>0$? then you would just have to justify more and prove more. why do extra work if less is enough? that's kind of thinking people have when proving a bit more complex stuff. just look at your post. the first paragraph uses $\ge$ and has 3 lines. the second paragraph takes care of $\ge$ and $>$ and is immediately 3 times longer almost. btw, $>$ implies $\ge$ so your argument that you can't apply the theorem is wrong. you just have proven extra conditions, you didn't disprove the sufficient condition.